# How to prove execution of contract method to a third party?

Tags: contract-invocation, dapp-design

Let us consider the following setup. Alice executes a method `doStuff(...)` of a particular smart contract deployed to an EVM blockchain under address `0x0123456789`. Execution of that method resulted with a transaction under ID `0xABCDF`. Alice wants to prove to Bob having executed `doStuff(...)`.

My questions are the following:

1. What is the most canonical way to prove having executed a method of a smart contract?
2. I assume they both have to be in possession of ABI and compiled contract. What other information does Alice has to provide to Bob?
3. How does Bob verify this fact? I'm interested in both abstract/theoretical description and practical (using `web3.js`, `web3.py` etc).

Many thanks in advance for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are events. They can be emitted on transactions and picked up by off chain parties. Read https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/contracts.html#events

Comment: I see! Thanks for answering! So for example, if Bob gets the `receipt` object from [this example](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html?highlight=event#events) would that be considered proven?